# set up re-direct for lan clients to local t&c page

Tags: redirect, local-area-network, captive-portal

I'm trying to set up something on my network so that when users connect and try and use the internet they are re-directed to a locally-hosted terms and conditions and policy page. Once they click "accept" then they will be passed through to their homepage, otherwise if they decline then the window will close or show them an error message.

I've spent a while looking into this and am wondering if it's possible to do witout having to setup/add to a firewall. Otheriwse let me know what my options are and I can pass it on.

Many Thanks
Tom

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captive_portal

Comment: bah, should have thought about wikipedia. Now I know what the proper name for the system is (captive portal? I would have never called it that) I can look into it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need a gateway device that is capable of this. As Zoredache points out, this is called a Captive Portal.

The only one I've had experience with is [PFSense](http://www.pfsense.org/), and you could set this up as a virtual machine on a low-utilised server.

Apparently you can do it by [following the guide here](http://www.andybev.com/index.php/Using_iptables_and_PHP_to_create_a_captive_portal) if you're running a Linux server.